# R: cut string of characters in vectors

Tags: r, text, vector

let `x` be the vector

```
[1] "hi"            "hello"         "Nyarlathotep"
```

Is it possible to produce a vector, let us say `y`, from `x` s.t. its components are

```
[1] "hi"            "hello"         "Nyarl"
```

?

In other words, I would need a command in R which cuts strings of text to a given length (in the above, length=5).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

More obvious than `substring` to me would be `strtrim`:

```
> x <- c("hi", "hello", "Nyarlathotep")
> x
[1] "hi"           "hello"        "Nyarlathotep"
> strtrim(x, 5)
[1] "hi"    "hello" "Nyarl"
```

`substring` is great for extracting data from within a string at a given position, but `strtrim` does exactly what you're looking for.

The second argument is `widths` and that can be a vector of widths the same length as the input vector, in which case, each element can be trimmed by a specified amount.

```
> strtrim(x, c(1, 2, 3))
[1] "h"   "he"  "Nya"
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `substring` see details in `?substring`

```
> x <- c("hi", "hello", "Nyarlathotep")
> substring(x, first=1, last=5)
[1] "hi"    "hello" "Nyarl"
```

**Last update**
You can also use `sub` with regex

```
> sub("(.{5}).*", "\\1", x)
[1] "hi"    "hello" "Nyarl"
```

Comment: +1 Or `substr( x , start = 1 , stop = 5 )` if you like to save those 3 characters of typing! :-)

Answer (score 1):

A (probably) faster alternative is `sprintf()`:

```
sprintf("%.*s", 5, x)
[1] "hi"    "hello" "Nyarl"
```